# How to get the text from an element which disappears quickly using protractor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

I need to get the text from element P but protractor keeps returning error

Code:

```html
<div class = "ui-growl-message"> 
    <span class = "ui-growl- title">Sucesso</span> 
    <p>cargo Cadastrado cm sucesso!</p>  
</div>
```

I've tried this way:

```js
const msgValidacao = element(by.css('ui-growl-message')).all(by.tagName('p')).first().getText().then(() => {
    expect(msgValidacao).toContain('Cargo cadastrado com sucesso');
});
```

and the Error is:

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector,
> ui-growl-message)

The problem is the element is a warning so it quickly disappears from the screen.

Comment: Your syntax for css-class is wrong. It should be something like `element.all(by.css('div.ui-growl-message p'))`
Tags are without prefix, classes are with prefix `.`
 It seems you didn't research much in how to select elements. The question is very basic.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I'm sorry, I'm very new in protractor and english isn't my first language so it's turns everything more difficult to research. =)

Comment: Don't worry about. English is rarely the first language for any of the people working in IT.

Comment: [Here you find an introduction video for CSS locators in protractor](https://youtu.be/sHyp7vk7DeE).
Also check out the other videos of this guy as he does a nice introduction to Protractor.
About timing issues, learn about `ExpectedConditions` and `Promises`. In general any knowledge about JavaScript, [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [Angular](https://angular.io/docs) including [Protractor](https://github.com/angular) will be of great help.

Comment: Thank you so much,this video will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the css correction, you'll also want to employ some sort of wait strategy to anticipate the message and grab the content as close to the moment of the initial rendering as possible. Automation around very short-lived messages can be challenging due to intricate timing factors.

Comment: There is not much context, to determine, whether the element is really disappearing or if it's just becoming invisible. Further should Protractor and Default timeouts automatically take care for this simple kind of timing issues. It only gets harder, if messages i.e. randomly appear after some time instead of an action or within loading.

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the real problem why it returns that element is not found. I thing that the selector is not good. If the element disappears quickly as You say sometimes the test will pass and sometimes it will fail. Try another selector and make sure that You have the correct one.

If you want to select first element use get(0) not first()

```
element(by.css('ui-growl-message')).all(by.tagName('p')).get(0)
```